# pip acts weirdly since few days

Tags: python, pip

With my Anaconda python27 install on Windows 64 bit, pip doesn't work anymore..

First of all, I tried to upgrade it, but it was up to date :

```
C:\Users\Administrateur>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages
```

I also tried to upgrade setuptools, it wasn't updated but it doesn't helped.
I recently tried to install few modules and it end each time with an error. For example, If I want to install pyx I get the following error message :

```
No files/directories in 
c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-soh1bb\pyx\pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

If I open a windows in my temp folder, I see that the files are collected then deleted just after. Also, this is not the same folder that the one cited in error.

If I try to install fiona, the error is different :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo 
/Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda\include" "-IC:\Program
Files\Anaconda\PC" /Tpfiona/_transform.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-
2.7\Release\fiona/_transform.obj
_transform.cpp 
fiona/_transform.cpp(564) : 
fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'cpl_conv.h'ÿ: 

No such file or directory error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft 
Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2


Failed building wheel for fiona
Failed to build fiona
```

And finally :

```
Command ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\...\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-h2ns8z\\f   iona\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-fme6kj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
 c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-h2ns8z\fiona\
```

I never had this problem before and pip is updated correctly, last module I installed is pygame could it be related ?

Comment: "never had this problem before" does that mean you installed fiona succesfully earlier?

Comment: before means I successfully installed some important package like  numpy, pycairo, scipy, panda etc... but  install pyx failed and fiona, there is others like 'shapely'. While writing this comment I tried to install 'twitter' and, surprisingly, it worked. wxpython too. since few day I noticed an accumulation of errors coming from pip and it makes me believe that maybe something changed, I am probably wrong.

Comment: some packages may fail to install because they require additional dependencies to be installed first. Some of these cannot be handled by pip itself. In this case it seems you need the GDAL development installation, see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you install is missing libgdal package. Install it first.

[Download Gdal Binaries](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries)